# Combination of incoming + outgoing + status?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

Is there an hg command that will combine `hg incoming` + `hg outgoing` + `hg status`?

This would tell you if there's anything remote that needs to come in, anything committed locally that needs to go out, or any local changes that need to be committed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Though you won't get the actual changesets or files, to get the current status summary, use the summary command:

```
hg summary --remote
```

Example output:

```
C:\Temp\repo> hg summary --remote
parent: 5:18ee64a17016 tip
 Added lots of unit-tests for DatabaseConnection.
branch: default
commit: 1 modified                          <-- status
update: 3 new changesets (update)           <-- local status, not at tip
remote: 1 or more incoming, 1 outgoing      <-- incoming/outgoing
```

Note that you only get counts, not the actual changesets, for that you need to execute the actual incoming or outgoing or status commands.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to [Generate a Diff Between Repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GenerateDiffBetweenRepositories).

As for local changes that need to be committed, that's just plain old `hg status`.

Answer (score 0):

Fog Creek software created an extension called "gestalt" which provides the following commands:

- `advice`:     provides a suggestion of your next step
- `next`:       provides an overview and explanation of what to do next
- `overview`:   provides a general overview of your repository state

The public repo for these extensions can be found [here](https://developers.kilnhg.com/Repo/Kiln/Group/Kiln-Extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since I'm here, I'll just drop a note on my solution to this exact problem. (provided you use bash or equivalent).

I simply defined the following alias in my .profile:

```
alias hgs='echo;echo "STATUS";hg st;echo;echo "SUMMARY";hg sum;echo;echo "INCOMING";hg inc;echo;echo "OUTGOING";hg out'
```

(for other shells, you might need a slightly different syntax for defining aliases).

Feel free to modify as required. I also included 'hg summary' in my version, but this is easy to edit out.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you want to [Merge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Merge)